# Probability of finding n particles in a volume v

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

I'm trying to calculate the probability of finding $n$ particles in a certain volume $v$ in a system with a total of $N$ particles and total volume of $V$. My problem is that I've tried two approaches which both seem valid to me, but give differing answers.

One approach is to use binomial probability, where the probability of success (particle in the volume of interest) is $\frac{v}{V}$. Furthermore, the particles are indistinguishable, so it doesn't matter the order of "successes" and "failures". This gives:

$P=(1-\frac{v}{V})^{N-n}\,(\frac{v}{V})^{n}\,\frac{N!}{(N-n)!n!}$

My other approach is to say to start saying that any configuration (remembering particles are indistinguishable) has equal probability and so the probability for our event is simply $P=\frac{\mathrm{\#\ of\ configurations\ with\ n\ particles\ in\ the\ cell}}{\mathrm{\#\ of\ configurations}}$. Now from combinatorics, the number of configurations is $\binom{N+\frac{V}{v}-1}{N}$, and the number of configurations with $n$ particles in $v$ is $\binom{N-n+\frac{V}{v}-2}{N-n}$. This gives a probability:

$P=\frac{\binom{N-n+\frac{V}{v}-2}{N-n}}{\binom{N+\frac{V}{v}-1}{N}}=\frac{(\frac{V}{v}-1)!\,N!\,(N-n+\frac{V}{v}-2)!}{(N+\frac{V}{v}-1)!\,(\frac{V}{v}-2)!\,(N-n)!}$

Which definitively isn't the binomial distribution, I checked numerically as well. So what is the problem?

Comment: "At least n" or "Exactly n" ?

Comment: It's exactly n.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in the second approach. How do you encode configurations? Just keeping track of how many of the $N$ particles are in $v$? If yes, then these are not equiprobable: just think of what happens when $v\ll V$; in that case, having all $N$ particles in $v$ has certainly not the same probability of having all of them in $V\setminus v$.

Comment: No, I encode configurations by how many particles are in each of the $\frac{V}{v}$ cells.

Comment: OP: No idea what made you accept the posted answer but be aware that it is not correct, for the reason explained by Yvan above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrepancy results from the fact that the first approach implicitly assume *distinguish-ability* while the second doesn't.

Let's take a simple example: $n=1$,$N=2$, and there are two cells($v=\frac{1}{2}V$), what's the probability to have 1 particle in the first cell? Now label the particles by $1$ and $2$(and remove the label in the end) and exam your two approaches.

1. There are four configurations, $[(1,2),()]$, $[(1),(2)]$, $[(2),(1)]$, $[(),(1,2)]$. You treat them with equal probability $\frac{1}{4}$. There are two configurations with only 1 particle in the first cell. So the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.
2. There are **only three** configurations, because $[(1),(2)]$ and $[(2),(1)]$ are the same physical states. The probability is therefore $\frac{1}{3}$.

The second approach is correct, because only different **physical  states** are equally likely.

**EDIT** Feb. 7, 2014: My conclusion was wrong, although particles should be indistinguishable.

OP and I implicitly assume there is only 1 microstate in each cell, which is not realistic. Suppose there are $M$ sub-cells in the unit cell with volume $v$; equivalently there are $M$ different states in each cell $v$. Let $\frac{V}{v} = C$, then there are $(C-1)M$ sub-cells outside $v$ as shown in the figure. 
[image: subcell]

There are $\binom{M+n-1}{M-1}$ ways to distribute $n$ indistinguishable particles into $M$ sub-cells in $v$. Similarly there are $\binom{(C-1)M+N-n+1}{C(M-1) -1}$ ways to distribute the rest $N-n$ particles into $(C-1)M$ sub-cells outside $v$. So the total number of configurations for exactly $n$ particles in $v$ is
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(n) =\binom{M+n-1}{M-1} \binom{(C-1)M+N-n-1}{(C-1)M -1}
\end{equation}
while the total number of configurations is the ways to distribute $N$ particles into $CM$ sub-cells, 
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=0}^{N}\Gamma(n) = \binom{CM+N-1}{CM-1}
\end{equation}

The probability in question is then
\begin{equation}
  p_n = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\sum_{i=0}^{N}\Gamma(i)} = \binom{N}{n} \frac{(M+n-1)!}{(M-1)!} \frac{[(C-1)M+N-n-1]!}{[(C-1)M-1]!} \frac{(CM-1)!}{(CM+N-1)!}
\end{equation}

Then we take the dilute limit, which means the number of sub-cells $M$ are large compared even with $N$. These factorials can be simplified,
\begin{equation}
p_n \approx \binom{N}{n} ( \frac{1}{C})^n (\frac{1-C}{C})^{N-n} =  \binom{N}{n} ( \frac{v}{V})^n (1- \frac{v}{V})^{N-n} 
\end{equation}
Oh God, I got the same answer as the first approach.

So there is no inconstancy for these two approaches after we take $M\rightarrow \infty$; that means particles even in $v$ can only occupy a small fraction of sub-cells, which somehow makes them effectively distinguishable.

Comment: Thank you! There's so much subtlety in these considerations. I had a feeling it was something to do with distinguish-ability. The second part of what I wanted to do is to take the limit for large $N$ and $V$ to show it's a Poisson distribution. I knew how to do this for a binomial, I'll see if I can get it too for the second one.

Comment: I can't get a Poisson distribution, in fact I seem to get something more like an exponential. I get $P=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{\nu})^{-(n+1)}}{\nu}$, where $\nu$ is the average ($\frac{N}{\frac{V}{v}}$). Wolfram|Alpha suggests it sums up to 1, so it seems valid, but it's not Poisson. Should I assume my problem sheet is wrong?

Comment: You have checked numerically that these two distributions are different even in the thermodynamic limit. Binomial distribution will approach Poisson, so the other one won't. Is there any experimental evidence that suggest it to be a Poisson distribution? If those particles are indistinguishable, I have to believe that the second approach is correct.

Comment: Hmmm... So, what you are saying is that, with N particles and two cells, the first cell has twice as many chances to receive between 0% and 20% of the N particles than between 45% and 55% of them because there are N/5 states in the first case and N/10 in the second case? This seems as wrong as can be since, when N grows large, the probability of the 45%-55% range goes to 1.

Comment: @Did, good question. The problem arises as there is only 1 microstate in the individual cell. If instead you have two groups, each have M cells, then the number of states of exactly n particles stay at the first cell is $\binom{M+n-1}{M-1} \times \binom{M + N-n + 1}{M-1}$. Calculate the entropy and using Stirling's formula you can get S. Then take the derivative with respective to n, you will get $n = \frac{N}{2}$. So equal partition does hold when $M$ is large(otherwise I'm not allowed to use Stirling's formula in the calculation).

Comment: @Did, let's think about the case when $M=1$, in a ideal gas system, where the two groups of cells correspond to two connected boxes with equal volume. Now each box has only 1 possible state, that means the volume is very small(only 1 cell) or the density is very high that are not experimentally accessible. So the statement "probability of the 45%-55% range goes to 1" can never been seen experimentally. In fact the concept of "thermodynamic limit" requires $N\rightarrow \infty, V\rightarrow \infty$ to apply our thermodynamic argument.

Comment: @Did, the only realistic model that have $M=1$ at the top my head the spin system. The multiple occupancies require the particle to be Bosons and they have to be confined to a two level degenerate system. I'm unaware of this kind of system. So please point out any real example that can show in such a two-state system of indistinguishable particles, "when N grows large, the probability of the 45%-55% range goes to 1".

Comment: Three comments, and I still do not see where you address the point I (after others) made. (Maybe a problem of language?) Anyway, first, $V$ is irrelevant, only the ratio $V/v$ matters. Second, as already said, for $V/v=2$ fixed (no limit here), the distribution of $n$ is not uniform (for no $N$ except $N=2$). On the contrary it is concentrating pretty quickly arounf $N/2$ when $N$ grows. Already for $N=16$ (hardly of Avogadro size), the range $(25\% N,75\% N)$ receives more than $95\%$ of the total mass, not the $50\%$ your solution predict.

Comment: @Did, you are right. I realized I need to encode the "configurations" in the second approach. Please review the edited version to see if there are any other mistakes.

Comment: Honestly I did not try to check the computations in your revised version but I see no reason why $p_n$ should not be **eactly** equal to $p_n={N\choose n}x^n(1-x)^{N-n}$ with $x=v/V$, for every $n$.

Comment: @Did, that's the basic assumption of quantum mechanics that particles are indistinguishable, see [identical particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_particles). So actually there is only 1 way of choosing $n$ particles out of $N$.

Comment: Do you really believe that? Wow.

Comment: @Did, yes I believe that because indistinguishability of particles resolves [Gibbs paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox). If you assume particles are distinguishable, then entropy is not an extensive quantity and the Gibss thought experiment will violate 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Sorry but to believe that, for 10 indistinguishable particles and 2 equal volumes, the split 0-10 has as much chances than the split 5-5 to happen, is to exhibit a deep misconception of what is going on. (And I do not plan to comment further on this question.)

Comment: @Did, that does not contradict our experience, because in these two volumes, there are $M$ states. As shown in my revised answer, the split 5-5 will dominant when $M \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I would have to agree with @anecdote here. In all our everyday experience M is huge, and probably infinite. On the other hand, when the number of states available is finite, you can get unintuitive effects like negative (absolute) temperatures. The interesting question for me here, is that even though particles in QM are a priori indistinguishable, does the fact that we are talking about'localizing' them in little volumes inherently makes them distinguishable?

Comment: @anecdote just to point out that while the rest of your calculation is correct, the binomials coefficient you write should have n, N, and N instead of M-1, (C-1)M-1, and CM-1, respectively in the bottom part.

Comment: @Did If we look at a boson gas and think of the little volume as a quantum state,then this state doesn't have substates and the original treatment by the OP holds. Calculations such as those found in here: http://www.nii.ac.jp/qis/first-quantum/forStudents/lecture/pdf/noise/chapter2.pdf show that indeed in these cases the variance goes as the square of the mean, indicative of an exponential distribution instead of a Poisson. Actually I just found that Wikipedia says it explicitly here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics#Derivation_from_the_grand_canonical_ensemble